# Bootstrap glyphicons not showing up in Spring MVC web project

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, fonts, glyphicons

I am trying to add the bootstrap glyphicons to my Spring MVC web project, but for some reason they won't show up.

I downloaded Bootstrap 3.3.7 and saved the fonts folder (containing the glyphicons files) under resources, along with the bootstrap.min.css.

The resources folder is properly configured in the dispatcher servlet:

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Following an answer from another thread, suggesting that Spring Resources Servlet won't serve .eot files, I added the following to my web.xml:

```
<mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
```

but it still doesn't work.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it: the problem was I saved the fonts folder at the same level of the bootstrap.min.css file, therefore the ref link inside the file would not find the folder.  Once I moved the  bootstrap.min.css inside the resources/css folder, the glyphicons finally worked.

In case somebody else incur in problems with the glyphicons, check that the hierarchy of your files is correct: make sure the fonts are in resources/fonts and the bootstrap.min.css in resources/css.